# Building EAR with multiple wars by accessing repositories remotly

Tags: maven, ear

I am trying to create ear with multiple wars. Let's say i have 3 web projects with the name web1, web2, web3. These 3 web projects repositories are placed in SVN. So now i wants to create a pom.xml file which creates ear with 3 wars by accessing 3 repositories in one ear file.

I tried it by placing all modules locally using below configuration.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                <defaultJavaBundleDir>lib</defaultJavaBundleDir>
                    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Description>${project.description}</Implementation-Description>
                            <Implementation-Vendor>Demo</Implementation-Vendor>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.demo.ps</groupId>
                            <artifactId>web1</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>web1.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/web1</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.demo.ps</groupId>
                            <artifactId>web1</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>web2.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/web2</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and under dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo.ps</groupId>
            <artifactId>web1</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo.ps</groupId>
            <artifactId>web1</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo.ps</groupId>
            <artifactId>web2</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo.ps</groupId>
            <artifactId>web2</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

by using above configuration it is creating 2 individual wars inside ear file, but i want some guidance to build same by  accessing both repositories remotely.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: By Repository you mean SVN ? In Maven everything is accessed via the repository which is a Maven repository which contains binary artifacts.

Comment: Yes it is SVN. I finally did using snapshots which are generated using Jenkins with maven configuration in remote server. Thanks for your suggestion.